How to gracefully shutdown/interrupt for loop in k8s container
I am new to golang.
I have a go program which is a for loop, like
for {
  f()
}

f may take seconds to 1 min. the for loop runs for ever, and can be killed by KILL signal.
in k8s container, we may kill the program/process very often. So i hope the KILL signal only interupt the for loop after function f finished and not started.
How to do this? Any example?
Thanks

https://pkg.go.dev/context https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal

I believe the "true" way is to give a context object to long-running or blocking operations so that they can be cancelled, and to pass this along to other, similar calls.

Who is terminating the program?  Why?  Is it significant that it's running in Kubernetes?  Is the signal SIGTERM or SIGKILL?  If it's SIGKILL, there's absolutely nothing you can do about it, but in a container context for a clean shutdown you're usually sent SIGTERM first.

To do something on a signal, you will need some code that listens for it. Note that you cannot listen for SIGKILL, but that is not the signal your application receives anyway (unless something like kill $PID is used). In most situations, your application will receive SIGTERM.
The simples way to listen for that is as follows:
quit := make(chan os.Signal, 1) // Create a channel for the signal
signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM) // Instruct the runtime to send signals to that channel
<-quit // Read from the channel. This operation blocks until there is something to read

Next, you will need to combine this with your infinite loop. We can use select for that. select is similar to switch, except that it checks every case for "is there something there yet"; if there isn't for any of the cases, the default gets executed. So perfect: you can use a case to check if you received a signal, and use default to execute your function otherwise.
quit := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

for {
  select {
    case <-quit:
      return
    default:
      f()
  }
}

For a small, single purpose application, the above is probably good enough.
For larger applications, it is common to create a "root context", wrap it using context.WithCancel(), pass that ctx into all goroutines. Each goroutine, instead of listening for a signal directly, checks for <-ctx.Done(). The main goroutine (or a separate, dedicated one) listens for the OS sigal and calls the cancel func that context.WithCancel() returned.
This later setup isn't only more scalable, but it also works together nicely with external code; for instance database/sql.DB.QueryContext() does the same trick of checking for <-ctx.Done() to stop what it is doing if the application is being shut down.
